# Add Decimals with Set Precision C++

Tags: c++

I'm designing a program that calculates 2 roots using the quadratic formula. I'm trying to get my output statements `root1` and `root2` to output with the number to two decimal players (i.e. 2.00, 5.00, etc.). However, when I use the setprecision command, it doesn't seem to work. For example, when I input the three points to be (1, -1, 2), I get the points (2, -1), not (2.00, -1.00) like I'm looking for.

Here is my code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C++
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double pointa;
    double pointb;
    double pointc;
    double discriminant1;
    double root1;
    double root2;

    cout << "Please enter a, b and c: ";
    cin >> pointa;
    cin >> pointb;
    cin >> pointc;

    discriminant1 = pow(pointb, 2) - (4 * pointa * pointc);

    root1 = (-pointb + sqrt(discriminant1)) / (2 * pointa);
    root2 = (-pointb - sqrt(discriminant1)) / (2 * pointa);

    std::cout << "Root1: " << std::setprecision(3) << root1 << endl;
    std::cout << "Root2: " << std::setprecision(3) << root2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Choose fixed point format by outputting [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: you use std::fixed instead of std::cout ?

Comment: the documentation linked to has some examples